# Curvilinear triangle grid

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics

I'm trying to figure out how the Adobe Illustrator's Inflate effect works. Basically, it converts a vector graphics object to a 3D mesh and displaces its vertices proportionally to how far they are from the object's borders. The resulting mesh's height is also controlled by the `Volume` parameter, which ranges from 0 to 100%. If I inflate a rectangle with `Volume` set to 0%, I get the following (flat) mesh:
[image: grid]
I wonder how can I get such a triangulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the method used in Illustrator is described in the following paper:

[Repoussé: Automatic Inflation of 2D Artwork](http://pushkarjoshi.org/pdf/JC_SBIM2008.pdf)

The mesh shown in your example seems to be a fairly regular triangular grid, displaced by the method.